# SQL Syntax Error | ORA-00904: : invalid identifier

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, syntax-error

I am getting this error while using Oracle XE 11g
I have been picking at this for an 2 hours and can't seem to find where the syntax error lies.

```html
CREATE TABLE vacation_unit
('VACATION_ID' INT NOT NULL COMMENT 'Vacation ID primary key',
  'LOCATION_NUM' INT NULL COMMENT 'Location Number',
  'UNIT_NUM' INT NULL COMMENT 'Unit Number in Condo building',
  'SQR_FT' DECIMAL (5,0) NULL COMMENT 'Size of COONDO unit in square feet',
  'BDRMS' DECIMAL (2,0) NULL COMMENT 'Number of bedrooms in CONDO',
  'BATHS' DECIMAL (2,0) NULL COMMENT 'Number of bathrooms',
  'VACATION_FEE' DECIMAL (6,2) NULL COMMENT 'Monthly condo fee',
  'OWNER_NUM' CHAR(5) NULL COMMENT 'Number of CONDO owner',
  PRIMARY KEY ('VACATION_ID') );
```

I've used those online syntax checkers and the second line keeps getting highlighted, but if I delete that line is then highlights the line that proceeds it. This leads me to believe there is something wrong with the entire structure of the code. 
Anyone care to assist?

Many Thanks,
Xlar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the quotes and move the comments to their own statements after the table has been created:

```
CREATE TABLE vacation_unit(
  VACATION_ID  INT           NOT NULL,
  LOCATION_NUM INT           NULL,
  UNIT_NUM     INT           NULL,
  SQR_FT       DECIMAL (5,0) NULL,
  BDRMS        DECIMAL (2,0) NULL,
  BATHS        DECIMAL (2,0) NULL,
  VACATION_FEE DECIMAL (6,2) NULL,
  OWNER_NUM    CHAR(5)       NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (VACATION_ID)
);

COMMENT ON COLUMN vacation_unit.vacation_id  IS 'Vacation ID primary key';
COMMENT ON COLUMN vacation_unit.location_num IS 'Location Number';
COMMENT ON COLUMN vacation_unit.unit_num     IS 'Unit Number in Condo building';
COMMENT ON COLUMN vacation_unit.sqr_ft       IS 'Size of COONDO unit in square feet';
COMMENT ON COLUMN vacation_unit.bdrms        IS 'Number of bedrooms in CONDO';
COMMENT ON COLUMN vacation_unit.baths        IS 'Number of bathrooms';
COMMENT ON COLUMN vacation_unit.vacation_fee IS 'Monthly condo fee';
COMMENT ON COLUMN vacation_unit.owner_num    IS 'Number of CONDO owner';
```

Answer (score 1):

Single quotes are for string literals.

You need to use double quotes `"` (for case-sensitive naming), or no quotes at all (case-insensitive).

Comment: @Xlar - and, it is best if you act "as if" column names in double-quotes don't even exist. Do not use column names that require double quotes (this includes column names that are reserved Oracle words, column names that begin with a digit or include any non-letter, non-digit symbols other than underscore, and case-sensitive names) Column names that require double-quotes only bring trouble to your database and your queries.